# Add FireWire support using M.2 to PCI Express x4

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, firewire, m.2

I want to add FireWire support to my computer (to capture some DV footage). The motherboard (Gigabyte Z390 AORUS Pro mITX) has the following PCI/M.2 interfaces (as according to the manual):

> *Expansion slots:*
>
> - *1 x PCI Express x16 slot, running at x16*  **<-- occupied by a graphics card**
> - *1 x M.2 Socket 1 connector for an Intel® CNVi wireless module only (CNVI)*
>
> *Storage interface:*
>
> - *Chipset:*
>
>   - *1 x M.2 connector (Socket 3, M key, type 2242/2260/2280 SATA and PCIe >x4/x2 SSD support) (M2P)*
>   - *1 x M.2 connector on the back of the motherboard (Socket 3, M key, type 2260/2280 SATA and PCIe x4/x2 SSD support) (M2M)* **<-- currently occupied by a M.2 SSD**

The manual states the following about the available M.2 sockets:

> ***M2P/M2M (M.2 Socket 3 Connectors)***
>
> *The M.2 connectors support M.2 SATA SSDs or M.2 PCIe SSDs and support RAID configuration. Please note that an M.2 PCIe SSD cannot be used to create a RAID set either with an M.2 SATA SSD or a SATA hard drive. To create a RAID array with an M.2 PCIe SSD, you must set up the configuration in UEFI BIOS mode. Refer to Chapter 3, "Configuring a RAID Set," for instructions on configuring a RAID array.*

Is it at all possible to use this adapter [Delock M.2 Key M male > PCI Express x4 Slot](https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_62584/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en) to connect the following FireWire card: [Delock PCI Express Card > 2 x external / 1 x internal FireWire A](https://www.delock.de/produkte/G_89213/merkmale.html?setLanguage=en)? I am unsure if the manual is actually telling me that the M.2 interfaces is storage only?